# Refresh ReportViewer Data

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, reportviewer

I have a report that takes its data from `table1`.

If I'm adding new data to `table1` the report won't update its data until I restart the .exe file.

Is there a command (C#) that I can use to refresh the data in the report ?

Answer (score 0):

`reportViewer.RefreshReport()`

Try google next time :)

Comment: Well i tried , not working the report still show the previous data and not the new i just added.
maby i need to refresh the dataset ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the RefreshReport method?

Calling the RefreshReport method causes all data in the report to be reloaded and rendered. A call to RefreshReport is automatically added to the Form Load event handler when a ReportViewer control is added to a form.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.reportViewer.RefreshReport();
  }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportviewer.refreshreport(v=vs.100).aspx